# How to see all the observers currently registered?

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, fatal-error

I'm facing a problem in which I have created an observer as follows:

```
<?php
namespace Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProcessGatewayRedirect extends ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    { 
        //die('order lllllllllllllllllllll');
        $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        $base_url = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order') ->load($orderId[0]);
        $payment = $order->getPayment();


        $method = $payment->getMethodInstance();
        $methodTitle = $method->getTitle();

        $order_data= $order->getData();
        $status = $this->checkoutSession->getLastOrderStatus();

          $increment_id = $order_data['increment_id'];
          $redirect = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http');
          $redirect->setRedirect($base_url.'custompayment/index/redirect/id/'.$increment_id.'');
          return;

    }
}
```

> events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="sales_order_place_after">
       <observer name="process_gateway_redirect" instance="Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Observer\ProcessGatewayRedirect" />
   </event>
</config>
```

Then when I run

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

command I get error as follows:

> Fatal error:  Class
>   Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Observer\ProcessGatewayRedirect cannot
>   extend from interface Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface in
>   /var/www/html/m4/app/code/Magento/SamplePaymentGateway/Observer/ProcessGatewayRedirect.php
>   on line 39
>
> Fatal error: Class
>   Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Observer\ProcessGatewayRedirect cannot
>   extend from interface Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface in
>   /var/www/html/m4/app/code/Magento/SamplePaymentGateway/Observer/ProcessGatewayRedirect.php
>   on line 39 Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Line 39 in ProcessGatewayRedirect.php is the closing bracket of the observer class.
I'm unable to figure out the real cause.

I doubt that my observer is not properly registered, so is there any fault in my code or is there any way we can list all the observers currently in our system?

Comment: You need to `implement` an `interface` not `extend` it. So it should be `class ProcessGatewayRedirect implements ObserverInterface`.